# How to get the private member of a derived class object constructed by the copy constructor of the base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

My classes have structure:

```cpp
class Base 
{
protected:
    int size;
public:
    Base(const Base &b); // copy constructor.
}
;
class Derived_1 : public Base
{
private:
    double phase;  // only Derived_1 has this private attribute.
public:
    Derived_1(int size_, double phase_)
}
class Derived_2 : public Base {};
class Derived_3 : public Base {};
```

I use `std::pair` to store the objects associated with another number.

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<int, Base>> num_base_list;
num_base_list.push_back({1, Derived_1{10, 90.0}});
```

How do I get the `phase` attribute from `num_base`?

I tried to use `dynamic_cast`

```cpp
Derived_1* derived_1 = dynamic_cast<Derived_1*>(&base);
// base is one of the Base object in the num_base_list
```

but received this error:`the operand of a runtime dynamic_cast must have a polymorphic class typeC/C++(698)` .

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you actually want to achieve and why you don't use polymorphism. Also, you can't take the address of a _type_ as in `&Base`. You need an _instance_ of `Base` if you want its address.

Comment: There are two issues in the code. (1) `std::pair<int, Base>` cannot store an instance of `Derived`. The initialization causes `num_Base{1, Derived_1{10, 90.0}};` object slicing. (2) dynamic casting is possible only for polymorphic classes. You make class polymorphic by making at least one function virtual. Start by making destructor virtual: `virtual ~Base() = default` which is almost always very important for the code to operate.

Comment: If you store a derived class into a base, you only get the base part copied and the rest is lost. See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: @ALX23z I've made some changes. Can you take another look at it?

Comment: It's still unclear why you don't use polymorphism and it looks like you didn't understand the comment about object slicing. Did you read the link provided by @BoP ?

Comment: Base classes shoudn't need to know anything about derived classes. This is an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to to get it you must have a pure virtual function for the `base` class which the `Derived_1` will implement with inheritance.
In `base` class : `virtual double getPhase() const = 0` to make the pure function.
In the dervied class: `override double getPhase() const` and implement it in the cpp

Comment: Why must there be a pure `virtual` member function? Sure, it'll postpone the problem to the other derived classes, `Derived_2` and `Derived_3`, so what's the solution for those?

Comment: beacuse you dont want to implement the method in `base` but in `derived` classes.

Comment: _"you dont want"_  and _"must"_ are different things. Also, I may _want_ a default implementation in the base class if it makes sense.

Comment: If you want to implement it you must have something in it.since you dont have anything to implement it with it will be probably pure, thats the whole concept of pure function.
For example: you cant do draw on `shape` class beacuse you dont know the shape.

Comment: I said _"when it makes sense"_. There is no **must**. Also, in this specific case, only `Derived_1` has a _phase_ so where does that leave the other derived classes if you have a pure `virtual` in the base? You've only moved the problem without solving the bigger issue that the inheritance scheme is most probably wrong to start with.